# Literata font license

Tags: font-licensing

I am planning to use Literata font for my marketplace item, but i don't know the license from this font.

I have tried to find, but not yet found word "license" in [this link](http://www.androidauthority.com/literata-font-download-play-books-609371/)

Anyone can give me reference about the license from Literata font?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Literata was commissioned from [Type Together](http://www.type-together.com/index.php?action=portal/viewContent&cntId_content=3301&id_section=141), a font foundry. I don't find license information in their official statements, but there isn't actually a place where you can buy / download it, so nowhere to put the license either.

It is definitely **not a libre font.** And I don't think you have access to a copy, unless you unpack the apk and take it from there - so not a legal access at least.

In short: Right now, no use of the font (outside of Google Play Books) is allowed.

Comment: This answer is no longer correct.

Answer (score 1):

In the mean time, Literata [was released](https://github.com/googlefonts/literata) with the OFL license.

When using it, make sure to only use a copy from that Github with the license and not some old font files which could have a different license.